# reducing execution time in python CGI programming

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi, response, python-multithreading

I wrote a program that gets source code, parses the htmlsoup, gets content like text from `<p>` tag and `<hx>` tag. Then further processes to extract keywords. Also, i'm about to extract image source and alt text.

via python CGI Programming, the program runs in browser. As i have listed above there are numerous task to do, so until the function (where extraction code is written) returns the browser keeps on loading. And this is as obvious that program waits for the function until it return or print something.
The loop below keeps ongoing for long... and the browser keeps on loading

```
[has imported beautifulsoup and termextractor]
def getContent(website):

 //made soup using beautifulsoup

for para in soup.findAll('p'):
    print "Paragraph : ", para.text
    print "<hr/>"
    keyword = extractor(para.text)
    for key in keyword:
        print "Keyword : ", key[0]
        print "<br/>"
```

How can i reduce the execution time ? run program in background ? or does multithreading solves this ?

What can i do for this script, as there is much task to do, as well i have to do the same thing for images found in website plus i'm planning for all found anchor tags to repeat the process.

Comment: first you have to profile, to see, where the most time is spent.

Comment: this might help you http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/ ... I dont think multiprocessing will help since apache or whatever should be handling all that